# Django and/or Ladon (exposing methods to several internet service protocols)

Tags: python, django, rest, soap, rpc

Is there an easy way to export django project functionality with multiple protocols like REST, SOAP (with wsdl file) and RPC?

Or may be it will be beter to use [Ladon](http://ladonize.org/index.php/Main_About) and write functionality without using Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. There is at least [tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) and [piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) but there are also [many others](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/).